# Jquery Multiple Selects on same page share same ID, different attributes

Tags: jquery

I have a page which has tabular data. Each row contains a select drop down. I have now been tasked to assign a dialog if a certain option is selected in the drop down.

```
<select name="warrantyStatus" id="warrantyStatus" claim="33555">
    <option value="0">Not Submitted</option>
    <option value="1">Submitted, Pending Approval</option>
    <option value="2" selected="">Approved</option>
    <option value="3">Approved w/Adj</option>
    <option value="4">Denied</option>
    <option value="5" disabled="disabled">Legacy</option>
</select>
```

If the select changes to value of 4 (denied) then I am trying to fire a dialog.

Here is my jQuery code:

```
jQuery(function($) {
    $('#warrantyStatus').change(function() {
        warSts = $("#warrantyStatus option:selected").attr("claim").val();
        $("#dialog").dialog({
            title: warSts
        });
    });
});
```

When I log this to the console, I only get results for the first select element. It will not work on the other select elements, again there are multiple select elements on the page sharing the same ID. I realize that we can not share element ID's in the DOM, but thought since the attribute ("claim") ID's are unique this would be permitted.

Comment: ID's **must** be unique.

Comment: Why don't you use a class?

Comment: The attributes make no difference to the ID. Plus, claim isn't a valid attribute. Use custom data attributes instead (data-claim="33555"). Note though that the IDs must still be unique.